# Why am I getting WebKitFormBoundary in my post request using the JS Fetch API?

Tags: javascript, django

I am trying to send data to my Django server from JS.  My code looks like this?

```
    let url = play_selected.dataset.url;
    const csrf_token = getCookie('csrftoken');

    let data = JSON.stringify( { selects: arr } );
    console.log(data);
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST', // Specify the HTTP method
      body: data, // JSON.stringify(data), // Convert data to JSON string (if object)
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', // Set content type header
        'X-CSRFtoken': csrf_token
      }
    });
    data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
```

The selects arr is just an array of numbers which I will eventually do something in my django back end.  Currently all I am doing is printing out the request.POST variable which is always empty.

When I print out request.body I get the following:

```
    (Pdb) p request.POST
    <QueryDict: {}>
    (Pdb) p request.body
    b'{"selects":["29"]}'
    (Pdb)
```

I would imagine that request.POST should display something similar to what is in request.body.

Why is request.POST empty?